# Monitoring java application memory in Task manager and Profiler, which is correct?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, profiler, visualvm

I'm monitoring the memory usage of an application running from Netbeans.  I'm somewhat confused by two different results.

The Task Manager gives me one value, whereas the Profiler in Netbeans indicates something different.

For example, here's the Task Manager screenshot of the application's memory usage to be 2,927.3 MB
[image]

But the profiler shows this (look at the upper right graph):
[image]
Where the total heap size is over 3GB, but the heap used looks just under 2 GB.

So to me the values don't match between the Profiler and the Task Manager.

Which one is the more accurate representation of the application's memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the memory consumed by a Java process is composed, at least to the best of my knowledge, by two segments.

**Heap**, which is the segment where objects are allocated every time the code execute sentences like CExample exam = new CExample();

**Non-heap**, this is the segment where you find the stack per thread and metadata classes that used to be called Permanent Generation and currently it is called Metaspace. As far as I know, the non heap also contains the native code generated by the Just In Time compiler to improve the performance of applications.

I think you can check these links to get more insights about heap and non heap segments.

https://betsol.com/java-memory-management-for-java-virtual-machine-jvm/

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html